# How do you return intermediary model while joining through several models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to figure out how to query activerecord and get back a list of objects, while joining through other objects.

Here is a simplified example.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wearings
  has_many :shirts, through :wearings
end

class Wearing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shirt
  belongs_to :person
  #has wear date + other attributes
end

class Shirt < ApplicationRecord
  scope :white, -> {where(white:true)}
  scope :large, -> {where(large:true)}
  scope :sleeves, -> {where(sleeves:true)}
end
```

People own shirts, and may even own several of the same color. In this case, I want to get back the wearings records for all shirts that match my criteria.

I can get the shirts back like:

```
shirts = person.shirts.white.large
```

I'd like to be able to do the same single query using scopes, but instead get back the subset of `person.wearings` that involved large white shirts.

This is in Rails 5.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways to implement this. Both of them produce same SQL request. We can add one of following scopes to `Wearing`:

```
scope :by_white_shirts, -> { joins(:shirt).where(shirts: { white: true }) }
```

or using [merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

```
scope :by_white_shirts, -> { joins(:shirt).merge(Shirt.white) }
```

the result will be like:

```
person.wearings.by_white_shirts
>>   Wearing Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "wearings".* FROM "wearings" INNER JOIN
     "shirts" ON "shirts"."id" = "wearings"."shirt_id" WHERE 
     "wearings"."person_id" = ? AND "shirts"."white" = ? LIMIT ?  
     [["person_id", 1], ["white", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```